# Using the filename as input for FileReader

Tags: java, filereader

How do I get a FileReader to read a file using the filename as input, rather than putting a direct filepath to the file? So instead of something like

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:file");
```

We have something where when we call FileReader(filename), we put the filename in as a parameter. So if I put in the command prompt:

```
Java FileReader input.txt
```

It will read the text file without me having to have put in new FileReader("C:input.txt").

Comment: How do you think the run time supposed to know the full path of the file ?

Comment: Simplely you can put files to the current working directory,then you dont have to write the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch your app like `java FileReader input.txt`, in the main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //args[0] is input.txt
    //but you still need the rest of the path e.g. C:\
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("path_to_file_location" + args[0]);
```